Looking for a German short story about how "there is no worse taste than half a cherry"
I think about this story so often and would love to own a copy of it.
The story tells of a man sitting in the train in post World War II Germany. He is eating a bag of cherries, enjoying the rare treat. When he is down to the last one, he realizes the boy sitting across from him was looking on in envy. He decides to gift the boy his last cherry. The boy is overjoyed - until his mother forces him to share it with his sister. Now there is barely enough left for either of the two children to get a proper taste of the fruit. "There is no worse taste than half a cherry", thinks the first-person narrator.
A story about how having not enough of a good thing can be worse than having nothing at all.
I read this story 20 years ago in a German school book. It was a very short story or possibly an excerpt out of a longer story. I remember it being less than one page. The story must have been written in the 50s in Germany.
Probably a long shot, but I would be grateful for any help finding this story that finds words for something that I find to be very true, but hard to express.
If you know of a different story that explores the same idea, I would be glad to hear of it as well.

Perhaps Das schwarze Leben by Peter Weiss. I found this snippet in Google Books:

Kirschen, erhebt sich und verläßt hastig den Zug. Dankbar genießen wir
die frischen, saftigen Früchte. Mein Blick fällt auf einen kleinen
Jungen, der mit hungrigen Augen neben mir steht. Und ich habe nur noch
eine einzige Kirsche übrig! Er bekommt sie. Sogleich will er sie in
den Mund stecken, aber seine Mutter ruft: teile mit der Schwester! Und
er beißt die Hälfte ab, nimmt auch den Kern und saugt an ihm, während
seine kleine Schwester die andere Hälfte erhält. Ich hätte die Kirsche
nicht weggeben sollen. Der Geschmack einer halben Kirsche brennt im
Mund wie eine Fäulnis. Die menschliche..

As it is snippet view, I'm unable to see the complete page and verify the title, but it appears in two Google Books records:
Die Besiegten by Peter Weiss and
Vom Nullpunkt zur Wende -: deutschsprachige Literatur nach 1945; ein Lesebuch für die Sekundarstufe by Hannes Krauss, ‎Andreas Erb.

From Google Translate: "My eyes fall on a little boy standing next to me with hungry eyes. And I only have one cherry left! He gets it. He immediately wants to put it in his mouth, but his mother calls out: share with your sister! And he bites off half, takes the stone and sucks on it, while his little sister gets the other half. I shouldn't have given the cherry away. The taste of half a cherry burns in the mouth like rot." Great find!

Great work.++++
